# sql dump of data based on selection criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When extracting data from a table (schema and data) I can do this by right clicking on the database and by going to tasks->Generate Scripts and it gives me all the data from the table including the create script, which is good.

This though gives me all the data from the table - can this be changed to give me only some of the data from the table? e.g only data on the table after a certain dtmTimeStamp?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend extracting your data into a separate table using a query and then using generate scripts on this table. Alternatively you can extract the data separately into a flatfile using the export data wizard (include your column headers and use comma seperators with double quote field delimiters).

To make a copy of your table:

```
SELECT Col1 ,Col2 
INTO CloneTable 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Col3 = @Condition
```

(Thanks to @MarkD for adding that)

Comment: ` SELECT  Col1
   ,Col2
 INTO CloneTable
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Col3 = @Condition` for the copy of your table